# MSVC function name mangling

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, abi

In Linux, the **GCC** compiler does not add the return type to the mangled name of a function, not causing an ABI incompatibility error in cases that a major version changes. Because of this, I usually use a **abi_tag** in a *inline namespace* depending on the major version to force this kind of behavior.

How **MSVC2017** mangle function names in Windows? I need to add something similar to **abi_tag** in the *inline namespace* to replicate this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVC mangled names include the return type.  See [Visual C++ name mangling](https://en.m.wikiversity.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B_name_mangling) for gory details.